# JDK is not recognized in Android Studio

Tags: jdk, chromebook, arm, android-studio

I am new user of Ubuntu LTS on a Samsung Chromebook Plus that has an arm64 processor. Android Studio won't install because it can't locate the JDK. I am trying to download and install the JDK, but there doesn't seem to be a install or setup sh file to run. I tried extracting it to `/usr/bin` but I don't have access.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Android Studio on Ubuntu which is installed on a Chromebook, but you don't need to install a separate Java package because Android Studio contains its own embedded JDK. You will get disappointing performance if your Chromebook does not meet the following system requirements.

#### System Requirements

- GNOME or KDE desktop
- 64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications
- GNU C Library (glibc) 2.19 or later
- 2 GB of available disk space minimum, 4 GB recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
- 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

[image: Y] 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator

To change various settings for your Android Studio project, open the Project Structure dialog by clicking *File* -> *Project Structure*. It contains the SDK Location which sets the location of the JDK that your project uses.

[image]